# Is there a Cocoa/Obj-C equivalent framework to log4net?

Tags: objective-c, logging

Looking for a good logging framework for a Cocoa App.

I've used log4net before for a C# app. Is there a similar thing for Cocoa?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [log4cocoa](http://log4cocoa.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Damn I searched for that but didn't find it. D'oh. Thanks